# Java - Getting a value from a mySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a question related to Java & mySQL. 
 I have a login and I want to extract some values from a row.
 This is how my table looks like : 
[image]

Once my login is successfull, I want to save into 2 variables the following : 
(My login works, I've just pasted the chunk of code where I have interest in)

The coins for the current logged int 
The privileges a user has in a String

In the main class I've declared the following

```
public static int coins;
public static String status;
```

This is the code :

```
      String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE username = ? and password = MD5(?)";

      PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement( sqlQuery );
      pst.setString( 1, Proiect_final.username );
      pst.setString( 2, Proiect_final.pw );

    //  // Coins extraction !
//      String sqlQuery1 = "SELECT coins,status FROM username WHERE username = ?";
//      PreparedStatement pst1 = connect.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
//      pst1.setString(1, Proiect_final.username);


ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
if( rs.next() ) {

   coins = [?];

   System.out.println("You did it!");
   mainFrm abba = new mainFrm();

   abba.setVisible(true);


}
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `coins = rs.getInt("coins");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider always retrieving the necessary columns, not all the columns from a table. So, change the query to:

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT coins, status FROM username WHERE username = ? and password = MD5(?)";
```

Then, execute it and retrieve `"coins"` column:

```
if (rs.next() ) {
    coins = rs.getInt("coins");
    status = rs.getString("status");
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods you are looking for are

```
rs.getInt("coins");
```

and

```
rs.getString("status");
```

Alternatively, instead of using the catchall '*' in your select, you could specifically name those two columns and then retrieve them by column order.  See the related API documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html